# Laravel share variable or object to all controller that is in Admin

Tags: php, laravel

In Laravel 6 I am creating an Admin area. For that, I have a simple Trait has an array of admin sidebar navigation items. To display menu items, I am passing it as a variable in view() as below

```
....

use AdminMenu;

public function index()
{
    // nav items
    $navItems = $this->navItems();

    //view
    return view('admin.dashboard.index', compact('navItems'));
}

....
```

Now with this approach, I have to use the trait and pass the variable in every controller in every method.

> #### Question
>
> So what I am looking for is the way so at one place I can set
>   this variable and it will be available in all `Admin/Controllers` (for ref. `namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin` ) and
>   its views.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside your trait's `navItems()` method you can put:

```
View::share('navItems', $whateverTheValueIs);
```

You will also need to import the Facade for View;

`use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;`

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't know about it. Thanks a lot. Just one more thing to clear. Where should I call `View::share()` in Trait's `construct()` or in the same method `navItems()` ?

Comment: Wherever you want. It's available globally to inject view variables.

Comment: I have added in my Trait method `navItems() { ... return View::share('navItems', $sideNavItems); }` but giving missing variable `navItems` error

Comment: Ah! damn.. I have to call the method in Controllers?? That way it works. There is no other way so without loading in the controller I can directly use it in all Admin views?

Comment: You don't need to return it, and you don't need to put it in the `compact(...)` line when you render your views... But yes, you will still need to call the function your admin controllers (maybe in the `__construct()` is useful?)